# How to pass '\x00' from python to c function?

Tags: python, c, ctypes

python:

```
msg = b'aaa\x01' + b'\x00' + b'\x23\x45cc'
dl = cdll.LoadLibrary
lib = dl("./test.so")
lib.send.argtypes = c_char_p
lib.send(msg)
```

c (test.so):

```
void send(char * msg)
{       
        // printf("%s", msg);
        SSL_write(ssl, msg, strlen(msg));
}
```

how can I pass '\x00' and what's behind it in?

Thanks!

Comment: You *are* passing it in. But, a hint: How does printf know where the end of the string is?

Comment: [\[SO\]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546). ***argtypes* should be a sequence**. *c\_char\_p* is for *NUL* terminated strings. If you want *NUL*s in your string, you should use *POINTER(c\_char)* (but you'd also need to pass the length). However *printf* is supposed to work that way (it would be the same behavior if calling it from *C*), so we're having an *XY Problem* here.

Comment: If you want to manipulate a string that might contain `00` bytes, then pretty much by definition you need to find a data structure *other* than a null-terminated string to do it with!  In C, at least, the usual way to do that is with a *pair* of arguments: a char pointer, and a length.  Can you rearrange your dll setup and calling convention to use that?

Comment: The other question is, given a char pointer and a length, how do you print it?  Obviously `printf("%s")` doesn't cut it.

Comment: What does this have to do with Python? If you called `send` from C with the same string literal, the same thing would happen.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I actually wanna call `SSL_write()`, but I will try to use POINTER(c_char), thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in comments, `printf` with `%s` only prints a `char*` up to the first null byte found.  The C function needs to know the size and some of your bytes are non-printing characters, so printing the bytes in hexadecimal for the specified length is an option:

**test.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

API void send(const char* msg, size_t size)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        printf("%02X ", msg[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

**test.py**

```py
import ctypes as ct

msg = b'aaa\x01\x00\x23\x45cc'
dll = ct.CDLL('./test')
dll.send.argtypes = ct.c_char_p, ct.c_size_t
dll.send.restype = None
dll.send(msg, len(msg))
```

Output:

```
61 61 61 01 00 23 45 63 63
```